# Failing to connect to EC2 via HTTP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

As the title says I fail to connect to an EC2 instance through HTTP.

I launched the instance inside a default subnet.
- This subnet is inside a VPC
- The VPC is attached to an IGW
- The NACL and Security Group allow all traffic
- The machine has a public ip
- I have installed apache by the following bash script (The EC2 instance runs on an Amazon Linux AMI):

```
#!/bin/bash
yum update -y
yum install -y httpd
service httpd start
```

What could possibly go wrong?

Comment: does the route table of the subnet your instance is in, have a route pointing to the IGW?

Comment: @GreenyMcDuff Thanks for answering! For some reason the default security group (which allows all inbound traffic) did not work. I had to make a new security group allowing traffic over port 80 with which I got it working